# How do I link a custom CSS designed button (class) using <input>?

Tags: html, css, class, button, hyperlink

I'm currently at a loss concerning this issue. What I'm making is a WYSIWYG editor (much like the one I am using right now) and the problem is the buttons on top. I have made a CSS class of their layout:

```
.test {
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.test:hover  {
    padding: 1px 6px;
    background-color:#789dfa;
    border: 1px solid #485ae0;
}
```

The layout works fine but I am unable to find a proper way to link the class. Take this for example(ignore the JavaScript):

```
<input type="submit" class="test" value="B" onClick="texta(text,'b','b')" onmouseup="text.focus();">
```

Problem is that any buttons (`<button>`, `<type="submit>` etc) tend to deform the original design, giving it 3-dimensional look and generally making it look more like a button.

My question is, how do I work around this? I've tried to link the class in several different ways but it just won't work.

Picture:

[image: button results]

Answer (score 2):

I usually go with:

html:

```
<div class="test"><a data-js="texta(text,'b','b')" href="http://someOtherLikeActionIfTheresNoJs"></a></div>
```

css:

```
.test {

    [ ... snipped your style ... ]

    position: relative;
}

.test a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That works brillianly if you actually mean to provide a custom button for an URL. Unfortunately the JavaScript (onClick) won't work when using <a>.

Comment: i usually use JS to stop the default action of <a>, then pick up a data-attribute from the tag to perform the onclick action.  That way, if the user doesn't have JS turned on, the link will still be there and work well ( if you plan ahead a little).

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your css just a bit

```
.test{
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
    border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;  //<--add this
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 7px;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
.test:hover  {
    padding: 1px 6px;
    background-color:#789dfa;
    border: 1px solid #485ae0;
}​
```

Works on input or button elements
Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/a9eNs/1/) with the result.